# Do I have to trust the client when using DreamFactory for my backend?

Tags: angularjs, backend, mbaas

I'm just looking into Dreamfactory, and it seems to me that all permission-logic is to be done by the client.

I want to develop an app with documents, and not all users are allowed to edit all documents. If the logged in user has permissions to the database, how can I prevent that user from making  false API calls that delete or modify someone elses document ?

Answer (score 1):

While your observation is correct, the app must control access, we do offer a couple features that will solve your problem.

First off, the roles system is very flexible. You could create different roles, reader, writer, admin, etc. And assign them to the corresponding users. This can be done today.

Secondly, we will be releasing an update in the next few weeks that has several new features, one of which, will also solve your dilemma. I'm not 100% sure what it is going to be named, but it will allow you to have the system automatically inject runtime data (I.e. user ID) into REST service calls to the DSP. Very flexible and powerful.

More information and doc will be available with the release so hold on a tad and we'll get you there!

Answer (score 0):

The upcoming release at the end of the month lets you do a server side filter, or use server side scripting to lock a user to modifying only their own records, or those you see fit.